# How to use class Attribute in swift?

Tags: swift

I want to know which method is best to use class attribute to another class.
I have a class

```
public class Loader {

    var xyz:String!

    public class var shared: Loader {
        struct Static {
            static let instance: Loader = Loader()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }
}
```

I can use this class attribute in two way.

first using singleton object

```
Loader.shared.xyz
```

second create a object

```
Loader().xyz
```

can you describe which method is best and why?
Thanks

Comment: If you got your answer mark as accept also if you have any confusion let me know!

Answer (score 2):

First of all the syntax to declare a singleton class is much simpler in Swift

```
public class Loader {

    var xyz : String!

    static let shared = Loader()
}
```

If you want to use the singleton pattern write

```
Loader.shared.xyz
```

that makes sure that you are accessing always the **same** instance and the **same** `xyz` property.

---

The syntax

```
Loader().xyz
```

creates a new instance of `Loader` (which is **different** from the *shared* instance) and the `xyz` property is also a **different** property.

Comment: if  loader class have a method `abc()` and I want to use in multiple classes then how to use that method? using singleton pattern or every time create new instance.

Comment: If the class is declared as singleton anyway use the shared instance.

Comment: If you are going to use this method, I recommend creating a private init() to ensure only the shared instance can be used.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a singleton class so the best method to use singleton class is:

```
Loader.shared.xyz
```

Because the loader in mostly cases will show on the window so whenever you want to show you can share a single instance of it.
If you make each instance newly so it is so typical to hide every instance from the application.

```
Loader().xyz //It will create new instance every time
```

**Note:** Every object has its own properties and behavior so every instance is different from each other.

Comment: can you describe why?